# How to perform the operation on the specific index selected in the array in javascript react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have one array of objects and I want to show on specific index the field that I want that is a text box inside row of a table.

Example of array of object as shown below:

```
const [showComment, setShowComment] = useState(false);

const data = [
    {
      "owner": "Joe Alex",
      "createddate": "21/04/2022",
      "comment": "None",
      "lastmodifieddate": "png"
    },
    {
      "owner": "John Doe",
      "createddate": "21/04/2022",
      "comment": "02/04/2020",
      "lastmodifieddate": "png"
    },
    {
      "owner": "Rahul Sharma",
      "createddate": "21/04/2022",
      "comment": "Abc",
      "lastmodifieddate": "png"
    }
  ]


{data.map((value, id, abc) => {
 {showComment ?
                        <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Enter comment" />
                        :
                        <div>{value.comment}</div>
                      }
  <div><Icon/></div>
   
}))
```

What I want is on the click of the icon by the help of the array index I want to show the the input textbox on the specific index selected. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to show multiple input for different row or one at a time?

Comment: only one that is input box textbox

Comment: on the basis of usestate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `id` to  `showComment` when you click on `<Icon />` and then compare during `map`, also you are missing `return()`

```
const [showComment, setShowComment] = useState(-1);

const data = [
    {
      "owner": "Joe Alex",
      "createddate": "21/04/2022",
      "comment": "None",
      "lastmodifieddate": "png"
    },
    {
      "owner": "John Doe",
      "createddate": "21/04/2022",
      "comment": "02/04/2020",
      "lastmodifieddate": "png"
    },
    {
      "owner": "Rahul Sharma",
      "createddate": "21/04/2022",
      "comment": "Abc",
      "lastmodifieddate": "png"
    }
  ]

  data.map((value, id) => {

    return (
        {id == showComment 
           ? <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Enter comment" />
           : <div>{value.comment}</div>
        }
        <div><Icon onClick={()=> setShowComment(id)}/> </div>
    )

  }))
```

Comment: but initially the input text is showing to me. I want it to be hidden in all the fields

Comment: then initialize showComment to -1

Comment: you did okay.. but can we do with usestate as boolean value? you have made it integer value.

Comment: you have data in array form, so its not posible with boolean value. Because with boolean value, we can able not decide which input have to be show?

Comment: I have to hide the icon div too when input is box is shown.. how to do it without boolean then ??

Comment: You can reset value of showComments to -1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247055/discussion-between-codenatial-developer-and-progpro).